# issue in re-rendering the path in a line chart based on user selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There is a strange issue I am stuck with. I created two line-charts with buttons to control the visibility of lines. In the second chart, the toggling of line-visibility works fine. But in the first chart, once it's rendered, if I try to toggle the visibility of lines, it doesn't work (all lines disappear). The code to create path doesn't even get called. The code to create path is:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .interpolate("monotone");

// ...

var lineInstance = g.selectAll(".line-instance")
  .data(filteredData)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "line-instance");


lineInstance.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    //this code is called when second-chart line is toggled
    // but not with first chart
    console.log(d);
    return valueline(d.values)
  })
  .style("stroke", "black");
```

After rendering for first time, If I toggle the visibility of any of lines of first-chart, both the lines disappear permanently. The code of both chart is exactly same. Tried to debug but no success yet.

[Here is the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ssw5kc01/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting up the variables for the line chart, you forgot a `var` statement at `g = svg.append("g").attr(...`. The `g` variable is hence added to `window` and not scoped to the `link` function. Therefore, the second instantiation of the line chart directive overwrites the variable - which results in that weird behavior.

Here`s a [fixed version of your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sfLrqrg/1/). I recommend using a JavaScript linter like ESLint which would warn you about such errors.